# Vapor Migration revert fails with MySQL error

Tags: swift, vapor

I've got a `Migration` that adds a foreign key field to a `Model`:

```swift
struct UpdateUnitTable1: Migration {
    func prepare(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        database.schema("Unit")
            .field("createdByUserId", .uuid)
            .foreignKey("createdByUserId", references: "User", "id", name: "created_user_id")
            .update()
    }

    func revert(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        database.schema("Unit")
            .deleteConstraint(name: "created_user_id")
            .deleteField("createdByUserId")
            .update()
    }
}
```

The `prepare` works, but `revert` errors with:

> caught error: "previousError(MySQL error: Server error: Cannot drop
> column 'createdByUserId': needed in a foreign key constraint
> '7b75a8aae1173c6c1f04cb626cadff7a5c321cf0')"

Thinking it might be that it can't be done in a single update to the schema, I tried:

```swift
    func revert(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        database.schema("Unit")
            .deleteConstraint(name: "created_user_id")
            .update()
            .flatMap { _ in
            return database.schema("Unit")
                .deleteField("createdByUserId")
                .update()
            }
    }
```

However, this just gives a different error:

> caught error: "previousError(MySQL error: Server error: Cannot drop
> index '7b75a8aae1173c6c1f04cb626cadff7a5c321cf0': needed in a foreign
> key constraint)"

Reverting to the original, single update and reversing the order of deleting the field and constraint doesn't help either. There doesn't seem to be a way of creating the index manually, so no way of deleting this prior to attempting to delete the constraint. Have I missed something?